# ImageMagick: Bold and Italic Fonts?

Tags: windows, imagemagick

When using ImageMagick from the command line, how do I specify a bold or italic font?

I have tried the `-weight Bold` and `-style Italic` arguments, but they have no effect, at least not on my Windows 7 system. I have tried calling typefaces by name (e.g., `-font "Arial Bold Italic"`) but I get the base font (e.g., "Arial"). I'm using -annotate to overlay a string on a picture.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try font name with hyphens: `-font "Arial-Bold-Italic"` - it worked on my Windows 7 (like you, I couldn't make `-style` option working). Order of styles (Bold-Italic) is important here.

To see all the fonts available to ImageMagick, use `convert -list font` (and additionally maybe `>C:\fonts.txt`, because the list is usually very long).

Comment: This doesn't appear to be working on mac os with .ttc fonts (worked for .ttf)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem: `-font "Arial-Italic"` did not produce italic and `-style` resulted in an error. However, `-font "Times-Italic"` works. For whatever reason, many of the italic fonts listed with `convert -list font` are not functional. Times-Italic is the only one I found that actually produces italic text. I use GraphicsMagick 1.3.28 on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.